# file does not strore in document directory

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, nsdocumentdirectory

I am storing an audio file with extension .m4a at document directory

first time my file store perfectly at the document directory path but

after that my file does not store at document directory path.

In console it shows me the entire path but in the document directory

does not exist. My code is as follows:

```
NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [path objectAtIndex:0]; 
        originalFilePath  = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:audioname];

        NSLog(@"Audioname:::: %@",audioname);

        NSLog(@"originalpath=%@",originalFilePath);
```

if you have any idea then share it with me.

Comment: After reading your last few questions. kEvin, NSLog(@"originalpath=%@",originalFilePath); will print a string. Because the string exists in memory has zero correlation to a file existing on your filesystem. Where is your code to save the file?

Comment: I second Paul's question: how do you save the file? if you show us the code, it will be easier to help you...